# vscode: Why do I have a green titlebar and sidebar?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Some windows in vscode have a green title bar and sidebar. I have no idea where it comes from. Has anyone seen this? I don't think it's a theme since it only appears in some windows. And I'm not sure if it's an extension since opening different projects with the same language doesn't always produce the effect. I could also imagine that it is OS X related. For sure, it is confusing.

**Edit:** The effect also persists when I disable all extensions and restart vscode.

[image]

Comment: did you download this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors?

Comment: @PeterHaddad nope. The only thing close to it is One Dark Pro, but deactivating it doesn't change anything.

Comment: look at all your `settings.json` files (global/workspace/workspaceFolder) to see if it sets the theme, or use the the theme selector to see which theme is used

Answer (score 4):

The project you open has been using Peacock Extension to color the Visual Studio Code workspaces separately.

[image]

Installing the Peacock extension in the Visual Studio Code will instantly fix the issue.